# Ask user to insert directory to create a folder and a file

Tags: python, file, directory

what I want to do with my code is:

1. Ask user to enter the path where a folder will be created
2. Ask user to name the folder
3. Ask the user to name the file
4. Write the text to a file inside this newly created folder

With my code, I created the folder, but it does not write the text to a file inside this new folder. Can anyone help me with that?

The error I get is below:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/word_concatenator_final.py", line 390, in 
    menu()
  File "/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/word_concatenator_final.py", line 384, in menu
    remove_paratext()
  File "/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/word_concatenator_final.py", line 342, in remove_paratext
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/no_tag/chap1.txt

My Code:

```
file_to_open=input('Enter your file name: ')

with open(file_to_open) as t:
    text=t.read()

pat=re.compile(r'(\[@PARAST@\]).+?(\[@PARAFN@\])')


s = re.sub(pat, '', text)

user=input('\n\nCreate a folder?| Y/N: ')


if user == 'Y':
    folder_path=Path(input('\n\nEnter your folder path: '))
    folder_name=input('\n\nName your folder: ')
    file_name=input('\n\nName your file: ')
    file_path=os.path.join(folder_path, folder_name)
    os.makedirs(file_path)
    file=os.path.join(file_path,file_name)

    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(s)
    print('\n\nText named', file_name +'.txt', 'written to a file. Check folder named',folder_name, 'in your directory')
else:
    no_tags1=open(file_to_open + 'no_tags.txt', 'w')
    no_tags1.write(s)
    no_tags1.close()
```

I expect to create write the text stored in a variable to a file inside a folder created and named by the user.

Answer (score 0):

The problems seems to be that the new directory that you try to create already exist.

You can see that with the line :

```
in makedirs mkdir(name, mode)
```

> FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/no_tags'

To solve this just add a try except around the line os.makedirs(file_path)

```py
try:
    os.makedirs(file_path)
except FileExistsError:
     print("Directory already exists")
     #Do something else or just pass
```

Comment: I've discovered the error. There was an extra os.makedirs. I've updated the code and now it works